# sqlite3 create another database from an existing database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a large dataset from which a subset based on some columns' values is wanted. I want to create another database from this subset. How would I do that with sqlite3 in Python?

```
The column from which I want to compare to get the subset contain date in the format of YYYYMMDD e.g. 20120429. 
I want to get the observation before a certain date.
```

Also, how can I winsorise and calculate the average value of some columns based on another column's value?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you create a separate question for the second part; it has nothing to do with the subject line and needs to be answered separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can `attach` the new DB file to an already existing SQLite connection (which has your existing DB open), then simply use the appropriate `insert` statement to copy the rows you want, adressing the tables in the attached DB using the DB alias:

```
attach 'newdb.sqlite' as newdb;

-- create table goes here if necessary

insert into newdb.table
select * from table where date < ...;
```